# Module is optimised and debug difficult even on a Debug build with optimise option unchecked

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have this web program that references several class libraries projects that we wrote within the same solution. But one of them is special: Breaking the execution during debug, I got `Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized` message when trying to watch some variables, and also some lines of code is skipped when stepping through. Every library else is debugging fine except for this one.

I used Debug->Windows->Modules and see that for this problematic DLL, module optimised column is a 'Yes'. I checked solution property, and confirmed active configuration is `Debug` for the solution level and also every project under it.

Also for the problematic project, I confirmed on the `Build` page that `Define DEBUG constant` is checked, and `Optimize Code` is unchecked. In `Advanced` page, `Debugging information` is `Full` - all same as other libraries.

Why would this one be optimised when every possible option I can find is set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Launch the Developer Command Prompt. Run `ildasm`. Open the problematic DLL and double click at `Manifest`. Found the following code:

```
  // --- The following custom attribute is added automatically, do not uncomment -------
  //  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/DebuggingModes) = ( 01 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 )
```

Mind that `01 00 02 00 00 00 00 00`. Open a normal debuggable DLL and find that value to be `01 00 07 01 00 00 00 00`.

This finally points to a line in Assembly.cs under that Properties of the project.

```
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints)]
```

Turns out one of the developers lost his code before he could commit and decided to decompile a DLL - unfortunately a release version - to get his code back and then commit it to the repo. Delete this line and everything will be normal again.

For the record, according to Dave Black from another post:

> If the DebuggableAttribute is not present, it is definitely an Optimized assembly

Inspired by https://dave-black.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-tell-if-assembly-is-debug-or.html